# Draw circle with different border colors Android

Tags: android

```
public static Bitmap drawCircle(int width,int height, int borderWidth) {
    Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(canvasBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP,      
            TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setShader(null);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);  
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    float radius = width > height ? ((float) height) / 2f : ((float) width) / 2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius - borderWidth / 2, paint);
    return canvasBitmap;
}
```

Simple this code draws a circle with white border, however I want part of the border to be black and the other part white. 40 % of it black, 60 % of it white

How can this be done?

Comment: You are on the way. instead of drawing circle, draw two arcs. one with white and other with black. see `canvas.drawArc(...)`. do some simple maths...

Comment: I am probabl;y having problems with drawarc params , for example this doesnt draw anything to me RectF rect = new RectF(10,10,10,10);
  canvas.drawArc(rect,0,180,true,paint);

Answer (score 8):

Try this code

```
class MyView extends View
{
    private Paint paint;

    public MyView(Context context, int x, int y)
    {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        // PorterDuffXfermode xfermode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);


        paint.setAlpha(255);
        // paint.setXfermode(xfermode);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        // setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here a utility method for filling a circle with one color and stroking the circle border with another color.

Use the second method to pass in an existing Paint instance, e.g. to set the anti-alias flag or to prevent memory allocations during onDraw().

```
public static void fillCircleStrokeBorder(
        Canvas c, float cx, float cy, float radius,
        int circleColor, float borderWidth, int borderColor) {
    fillCircleStrokeBorder(c, cx, cy, radius, circleColor, borderWidth, borderColor, new Paint());
}

public static void fillCircleStrokeBorder(
        Canvas c, float cx, float cy, float radius,
        int circleColor, float borderWidth, int borderColor, Paint p) {

    int saveColor = p.getColor();
    p.setColor(circleColor);
    Paint.Style saveStyle = p.getStyle();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    c.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, p);
    if (borderWidth > 0) {
        p.setColor(borderColor);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        float saveStrokeWidth = p.getStrokeWidth();
        p.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
        c.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius - (borderWidth / 2), p);
        p.setStrokeWidth(saveStrokeWidth);
    }
    p.setColor(saveColor);
    p.setStyle(saveStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just draw your circle at full size with one color, then draw the circles again at the same coordinate, but with a different color and with a smaller radius, and scale down the radius however much you need to, that would be the most trivial way to do it.